# iOS multi language from database

Tags: mysql, objective-c, multilingual

A year ago i created an Application in dutch. Now I want to make this app multi language. I read that xcode has localized strings but all my text is downloaded from a MySQL database in an external location so there is no Local text.
Do I need to create this from ground up? My idea was reading the users preferred language setting. Then pointing to the right table in the database. Is this the best way to support multi language application from a database?

Btw the current method is just downloading the desired content from MySQL with php and json.

Comment: damn you for down voting this. This question is legit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-create your application only to the extent that you need to store your text as part of your application. Whatever else you're loading from your database shouldn't be an issue. But Cocoa's (not Xcode's) localization scheme dictates that the text to be localized be stored as part of the application.

That being said, what do you do? Start by reading [Apple's very own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005) on the subject. There's also a link within that, [Preparing Your Nib Files for Localization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002138-BBCBFFDF) that you should read as well.

You'll need to create a `Localizable.strings` file for each language you wish to support. Each of these files contains key/value pairs as described in the documentation. The key is a string that can be any arbitrary value, but it has to remain consistent across all of your `Localizable.strings` files. The value is the string rendered in the given language for that file.

Think about why you're loading your text from a database. It might be because *some* of it needs to be updated, but surely not all of it.

Best wishes to you in your endeavors ahead.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, I didn't think your downvote was fair, either.